# Border has background color seeping through it

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm setting the background color to a white border and the border is seeping through the background.I'm looking to have the blue line gone. Can you please suggest a solution to this problem?

Here is my code below. And there is an image of what I'm talking about below.

[[image: Border example Image]

```
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3
self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(CircleDiameter/2)
```

Comment: did you set `self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true`?

Comment: Also, could you describe what it is that you want? Did you want the blue line to be thicker, or gone?

Comment: I want the blue line to be gone

Comment: Masking it to bounds didn't work either

Comment: Is it possible that you have some other view below? Is it gone when you set background color to something else? Or is the line green when you set background to green?

Comment: yes it is. I've tested other colors

Comment: Is it a native ImageView or your custom? Maybe with some custom drawing?

Comment: if you background is white anyway, why don't you just get rid of the border completely and change the size of the imageView instead?

Comment: its a native image view

Comment: the background isn't white. There is an image view behind it that is empty. The border is supposed to create transparency. The image view right now is clear because it has no data behind it

Comment: I also made it clear to highlight the problem

Comment: Hey John, there's another post that is similar to yours and they don't have a solution, but rather a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350689/borders-not-covering-background

Comment: Do you override draw method in you view? If you do, can you show us the code?

Comment: i don't override draw the method

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what iOS rendering do with a layer have positive cornerRadius, I have Tested add a white circle view overlap a blue circle view which has the same size, the same situation appears:

### [image]

In fact, through [borderWidth  Document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410917-borderwidth) the border of layer is drawn inset from the receiver’s bounds, so it has the same kind of situation as I mentioned above:

> When this value is greater than 0.0, the layer draws a border using the current borderColor value. **The border is drawn inset from the receiver’s bounds by the value specified in this property. It is composited above the receiver’s contents and sublayers and includes the effects of the cornerRadius property.**

So borders + roundness = sadness on iOS and I think you need another way to implement your design.